# ansible variables in inventory

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to store variables in inventory files?

My inventories looks like this:

```
[a]
host1
[b]
host2
[Dev:children]
a
b


[a]
host3
[b]
host4
[Dev:children]
a
b
```

As you can see Both inventories are used on Dev vars (because 99% percent of the variables are the same) but few of them differ. Is that possible to add them to role just by running the role with correct inventory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the answer is: [Ansible - variables in inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#group-variables)

To put it simply, just use the following syntax:

```
[a:vars]
var=abc
```

By running the role with that directory, you can user variable var :)