# Ansible use variables in inventory

Tags: ansible

I have a ec2 instance [10.0.0.100] with follow private key: test01.pem

I have a ec2 instance [10.0.0.200] with follow private key: test02.pem

i have a host file in my personal pc:

hosts

```
[production]
10.0.0.100 ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/ok/test01.pem
10.0.0.200 ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/ok/test02.pem
```

I would like to have something like:
hosts

```
[vars]
test01_pem=/ok/test01.pem
test0_pem=/ok/test02.pem

[production]
10.0.0.100 ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu ansible_ssh_private_key_file=$test01_pem
10.0.0.200 ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu ansible_ssh_private_key_file=$test02_pem
```

How can i to make this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ansible variables in inventory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39387238/ansible-variables-in-inventory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with other ansible definition, you have to use jinja2 templating. Moreover, you need to declare your "global" vars attached to the "all" group. I suggest you go over the [inventory documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) to learn more.

As a quick example starting from you ini inventory this would give:

```
[all:vars]
test01_pem=/ok/test01.pem
test02_pem=/ok/test02.pem

[production]
10.0.0.100 ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu ansible_ssh_private_key_file="{{ test01_pem }}"
10.0.0.200 ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu ansible_ssh_private_key_file="{{ test02_pem }}"
```